# I am wondering why the following outputs (529, 23) rather than (484, 22)

Tags: python

```py
for x in range(0,501):
    
    m = x ** 2
    if m > 500:
        break
        
print (m,x)
    
#this outputs a value for the highest square that is above 500 when I want the highest that is below 500
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to print `((m-1)**2, x-1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code assigns the value of `m` before breaking, so it stores that value before breaking.
Try this instead:

```py
for x in range(0, 501):
    if (x + 1) ** 2 > 500:
        m = x ** 2
        break
print(x, m)
```

### Notes

Since you're new and it sounds like you're still learning about coding, I will add a few pointers.

First, you don't need to assign value to `x` to test the value of a function applied to it. Second, a better approach would be to use a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop, like this:

```
x = 0
while (x + 1) ** 2 < 500:
    x = x + 1
print(x, x**2)
```

Additionally, loops are slow, brute force ways to write code. Sometimes that's okay or necessary, but when there's a very efficient way to solve a problem without a loop, it's usually better to use it. For example, to find the smallest integer whose square is less than or equal to x, we can use:

```
import math
def int_root(x):
    return int(math.sqrt(x))
int_root(500)
```

Comment: Thank you! All of these comments are good, but I find yours to be the best. I am, in fact, new, and this post was very helpful. Would you mind explaining the second program, the one that starts with x = 0? I think I understand how it works but am not really sure what happens to X when it is reassigned. How does x equal both x and x+1? Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks. If you like my answer, please mark it as the accepted one! The second one starts with zero. Then it tests whether zero + 1 squared is less than your target number. If it is, it increases x by 1 and checks that `(1 + 1)**2`. It keeps doing this until the condition x + 1 is false. A `while` loop goes on and on until test condition is false. Then it goes the the final line, `print(x, x**x)`  By the way, the reason a `while` loop is better than a for loop is because once you find the number, the for loop will still check every larger number. The while loop stops when the number is found.

Answer (score 0):

You break the loop after `m` already exceeds `500`, so `(529, 23)` is expected. Note that `23 ** 2 = 529`. You want to retreat to the previous `x` and previous `m` in this case.

```
for x in range(0,501):
    m = x ** 2
    if m > 500:
        x -= 1
        m = x ** 2
        break
        
print (m,x) # 484 22
```

Or check the next `x` to break before exceeding 500:

```
for x in range(0,501):
    m = x ** 2
    if (x+1) ** 2 > 500:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are breaking the loop once the value for `m` has already exceeded 500. So when you try to print the value for `m` it is the value that is above 500.

A solution would be to use the value of `x` and because we know that the desired value would be one less than this, we can compute `m` like so:

```
for x in range(501):
    m = x ** 2
    if m > 500:
        break

x -= 1
print(x**2, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

```
n = 0
for x in range(500):
    m, n = n, (x + 1) ** 2
    if n > 500:
        break
        
print(m, x)  # 484 22
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others the issue with your code is that when you check to see if m is greater than 500, if m is exceeding 500 the program breaks the loop, the catch is that m has already been given the value that is over 500 and as such prints that out instead of the desired one before. To counteract this we can add to x and square the result to see if that answer is over 500 and if it is the program will break.

```
def squareless(top):
    for x in range(0, top):
        if (x + 1) ** 2 > top + 1:
            m = x ** 2
            print(x, m)
            break
squareless(500)
```